# JavaFX Line numbers doesn't work if there's no content on line

Tags: javafx, line-numbers

I have tried a little bit with line numbers today but I have just one problem I can't fix.

It can count how many lines there are if the line contains any content but if it doesn't have any content it just say 0.

And i get the text from a TextArea in JavaFX.

Here's my simple code

```
GetArea().setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent ke) -> {
            if (ke.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)){
                int m = GetArea().getText().split("\n").length;
                System.out.println(m);
            }
        });
```

Comment: The problem is every time I make a new line it doesn't count it. But If the line contain any contents it work...

Answer (score 0):

The method **split** searches the string for substrings that match the regular expression, spliting the sentence at that point and excluding the matching substring. Take a look at these examples:

- "This is a test string.\nAnd this is another one." will result in ["This is a test string.", "And this is another one."] and the count will be 2.
- "This is a test string.\n" will result in a ["This is a test string."] and so the result will be 1.

To obtain the result you want, you can, for instance, test if the last character in the string is a '\n' and add 1 to the line count, thus obtaining something like this:

```
GetArea().setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent ke) -> {
        if (ke.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)){
            String text = GetArea().getText();
            int m = text.split("\n").length;

            if(text.charAt(text.length() - 1) == '\n')
                m++;

            System.out.println(m);
        }
    });
```